# Как правильно сделать подсчет значений по нажатию?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Идея была простая: по нажатию на li, ему переключается класс на active (для стилизации и для перехвата активного элемента в js), значение его data забирается и, суммируясь со всеми active, пишется в #result.

Статично, при загрузке сделать получается, а вот, чтобы шел перерасчет по клику - пока никак... Или только в + - суммируется постоянно. А надо, соответственно, чтобы отсутствие active у элемента, забирало его значение из суммы...

Такой html:

```
<ul class="symptom-list">
    <li data="3" class="active">Симптом 1</li>
    <li data="4" class="active">Симптом 2</li>
    <li data="5" class="">Симптом 3</li>
    <li data="6" class="">Симптом 4</li>
    <li data="7" class="">Симптом 5</li>
</ul>
<div class="symptom-result">
    <p><span id="result">0</span></p>
</div>
```

И текущая попытка в js:

```
var summ = 0;
var elem = $('.symptom-list li.active');

$(".symptom-list li").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    $.each(elem, function(){
        summ += parseInt($(this).attr('data'));
    })
    $('#result').html(summ);
});
```

Чуть доработанная версия кода @Arendach, являющаяся правильным ответом:

```
$(document).on('click', '.symptom-list li', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    var elem = $('.symptom-list li.active');
    var sum = 0;
    $.each(elem, function () {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr('data'));
    });

    $('#result').html(sum);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая проблема в том что вы вынесли переменную `sum` за пределы события, а надо чтобы при каждом клике переменная обнулялась(после клика присвоить ей значение 0)

И вторая проблема то что `var elem` тоже определена еще до события, то есть цикл ходит постоянно по одним и тем же элементам.

```
$(document).on('click', '.symptom-list li', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");

    var sum = 0;
    $.each('.symptom-list li.active', function () {
        sum += parseInt($(this).attr('data'));
    });

    $('#result').html(sum);
});
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, эту логику я не учел. На сайте стоит jQuery v1.11.2 - в консоли получаю ошибку при клике "Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '22' in .symptom-list li.active"

Comment: Метод on() введен в jQuery-1.7, чтобы объединить три метода библиотеки, устанавливающие обработчики событий на элементы страницы: .bind(), .delegate(), .live(). Сами эти методы считаются теперь устаревшими, хотя еще поддерживаться. Установить обработчик, срабатывающий только один раз, по прежнему можно только с помощью отдельного метода .one().

Comment: добавил, как вы и сказали, в ваш код var elem с li.active и уже elem после each в код - все заработало! Я ваш код чуть поправлю, как заработало у меня, чтобы с чистой совестью отметить решением. Большое спасибо!

Comment: @Sepika Не надо пытаться править сообщение автора. Отклонил правку. Если вы хотите -- можете в комментариях описать или отдельным ответом или вносить правку но всё же только после того как он согласится.

Comment: @Arendach Просмотрите [правку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/309318).

Comment: советую использовать свежие версии jquery, версия 1.1.2 вышла еще в далеком 2007 и считается устаревшей

Comment: @Arendach У меня 1.11 - не самая новая, да, но...

Comment: стабильной к слову считается 3.3.1 дело ваше, просто советую

Comment: @Arendach спасибо - давно пора обновлять, да